How to use fling animation in tester in flutter integration_test?
I am trying to achieve a fling animation on the map ClipRRect but unabale to do while using tester.fling. How can I achieve this in flutter integration testing?
          await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key("create_plate")));
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
          expect(find.byKey(const Key('find_plate_key')), findsOneWidget);

          await tester.fling(find.byKey(const Key('find_plate_key')), const Offset(100, 100), 2000);

          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));

The code below is the widget for GoogleMap:
ClipRRect(
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
child: Stack(
    children: [
        GoogleMap(
            key: const Key('find_plate_key'),
),],),)...

